# Cells in columns need to have only 3 digits or characters

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check cells in columns that have only 3 digits or 3 characters if not error message, for any format. my code is below it does not work for me when column cells values are in the 'custom/special' format. for example if cells has 001 or 000 it does not count as 3 digits. pls help

```
Sub three_digits()
Dim c As Range
Dim alastrow As Long
alastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Range("B2:C2" & alastrow)
If Len(c.Value) <> 3 And c.Value <> "" Then
MsgBox "Error" & c.Address


   
  End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Text` instead of `Value`

Comment: @TimWilliams perfect! also is there way to make sure its only 3 numbers would istext work ? or another way

Comment: In your code, your just saying that if c.Value not equal to 3 Then.... If you want it to be max length of three, just change it to Len(c.Value) = 3. That is the equivalent of only 3 in length, excluding all values above and below.

Comment: @HavardKleven is there way to make sure its only 3 numbers and exclude alpha characters, would istext work ? or another way

Comment: I cant test it right now, but this should work: [...] And IsNumeric(c.Value) = True

Comment: @HavardKleven is this the right syntax If Not IsNumeric(c.Value) = True And Len(c.Text) = 3 And c.Text <> "" Then ?  its only working the first part of the statement

Comment: `If c.Text Like "###" Then`

Comment: @TimWilliams works! thank you all for the help